# Why does this snippet with import_module fail?

Tags: python, macos, python-import

The following code creates a Python package `a.b.c`, then tries to import it. It fails, but works fine if I comment out the line `import_module('a.b')` inside the try/except!

```
import os.path
from importlib import import_module
import os
import shutil
import sys

shutil.rmtree('a', ignore_errors=True)

os.makedirs('a')
with open('a/__init__.py', 'w'):
    pass

try:
    # it works if i comment out the following line!
    import_module('a.b')
    pass
except ImportError:
    pass
print(sys.modules.get('a'))

os.makedirs('a/b/c')

with open('a/b/__init__.py', "w"):
    pass

with open('a/b/c/__init__.py', "w"):
    pass

import_module('a.b.c')
print('ok')
```

When i run it on my Mac (official Python 3.6 installation), I get:

```
<module 'a' from '/Users/chris1/Documents/a/__init__.py'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/chris1/Documents/foo3.py", line 35, in <module>
    import_module('a.b.c')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 936, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 948, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'a.b'
```

This issue only happens on my Mac, not my Windows Python 3.6.

It seems that on Mac, the `import_module` is adding `a` to `sys.modules`; I think this could be connected to why the later import fails.

Comment: Why are you trying to import `a.b` before creating it in the first place?

Comment: This code is an extreme simplified version of a bug I encountered where a 3rd party package was importing a module (I have no control over it).

Comment: i can't reproduce your error on my Mac. I get the `ok` and it doesn't throw any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear that `importlib` caches the result of your failed import of `a.b`. When you try to import `a.b.c` it already thinks `a.b` doesn't exist, even though you created it. You would have to call `invalidate_caches()` from the `importlib` package before trying to import again.

Reference: https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module

> If you are dynamically importing a module that was created since the 
>   interpreter began execution (e.g., created a Python source file), you 
>   may need to call `invalidate_caches()` in order for the new module to be
>   noticed by the import system.